# The first forty years of life give us the text, the next thirty supply the commentary

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does the following bold part mean?

> *The same truth may be more broadly expressed by saying that **the first forty years of life furnish the text, while the remaining thirty supply the commentary;** and that without the commentary we are unable to understand aright the true sense and coherence of the text, together with the moral it contains and all the subtle application of which it admits.*
>
> ―[Arthur Schopenhauer, *The Wisdom of Life and Counsels and Maxims*](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/schopenhauer/arthur/counsels/chapter5.html)

I can’t see the link between the text and commentary.

Comment: Wait 'til you're 40...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This comment by Schopenhauer is old and well known.

Text and commentary are linked. The Bible is a text; the commentaries on the bible (reflections on what the text means) are numerous and exhaustive. The same holds for the Torah, the Quran, the sayings of Buddha, or any important religious text. Political commentary begins immediately after an important politician makes a pronouncement. Commentary is simply *explanatory or critical notes on a text*.

What happens at forty (or thereabouts)? One stops just the consuming activities of daily living, and starts reflecting on what a life has meant. One provides a commentary on the text of living.

In a similar vein, Socrates said:

> "...and if I say that the greatest good of a man is daily to converse about virtue, and all that concerning which you hear me *examining myself and others*, and that ***the life which is unexamined is not worth living*** — that you are still less likely to believe.

Answer (score 1):

> "By the age of 40, a great number of people are approaching that magic part of their lives, where they become grandparents. Some sooner, some later, but their lives change.
>
> With that change, they begin to see things differently, especially the relationships within the family. Things start to change, and explanations (or excuses) for prior behavior become common.
>
> In this manner, the older generation gives to the younger generations their accumulated wisdom, either by word or by deed, either what to do, or what not to do. But that provides commentary on their lives in any case."

[Source](http://philosiblog.com/2014/01/07/the-first-forty-years-of-life-give-us-the-text-the-next-thirty-supply-the-commentary-on-it/)

Comment: Schopenhauer also said, "If there is anything in the world that can really be called a mans property, it is surely that which is the result of his mental activity."

Comment: Is a quadragenarian what it was?  I wonder if  introspection has changed too